# Rendering templates with different models into named outlets in Ember.js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I want to render 2 lists of items, both templates that `each` over the model.

I tried to render the main template first and then the nested ones into some named outlets of the main template, which works.

But when I try to give the nested ones a different model (they all use different model arrays), I get an error:

```
 The value that #each loops over must be an Array.
 You passed '<DS.PromiseArray:ember451>' (wrapped in (generated homepage controller))
```

Here is the code:

```
renderTemplate:function(){
  this.render('homepage');

  this.render('roomlist',{
    'into':'homepage',
    'outlet':'roomlist',
    'model':this.store.find('room')
  });

  this.render('activitylist',{
    'into':'homepage',
    'outlet':'activitylist',
    'model':this.store.find('activity')
  });
}
```

Edit:

Alternative idea I had, was to use `{{render "roomlist" rooms}}` after `this.set("rooms", this.store.find("room");` in the model-hook instead of the renderTemplate-hook. But it threw almost the same error:

```
The value that #each loops over must be an Array.
You passed (generated roomlist controller)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should resolve the models you will use in the `model` hook, and then you can use them in your templates much easier:

something like this:

```
model: function() {
  return Ember.RSVP.hash({
    rooms: this.store.find('room'),
    activities: this.store.find('activity')
  });
},
setupController: function(controller, model) {
  this.set('rooms', model.rooms);
  this.set('activities', model.activities);

  controller.set('model', model.rooms);
},

renderTemplate: function(){
  this.render('homepage');

  this.render('roomlist',{
    'into':'homepage',
    'outlet':'roomlist',
    'model':this.get('rooms')
  });

  this.render('activitylist',{
    'into':'homepage',
    'outlet':'activitylist',
    'model':this.get('activities')
  });
}
```

Comment: is there a way to load the models in the nested-template-specific controllers? since those nested templates don't have their own route, I tried to load their models in the main template, but this doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: you can try setting all models on the parent controller, and then in your template do `{{render 'nested-controller' somemodel}}`